# RegExp over electron ipc turns into plain object

Tags: javascript, regex, electron

I'm building a little application in electron, and need to send an filter Object with a RegExp from the renderer process to the main process. I'm using the following code in the renderer process to call the method on the main process:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote,
      Filter = remote.require('./filter.js'),
      filterInstance = new Filter();

let filter = {
    $regex: new RegExp(/inventaris/i)
};

filterInstance.find(filter);
```

On the render process `filter.$regex instanceof RegExp` returns true.
On the main process `filter.$regex instanceof RegExp` retuns false.

After a little digging I found out that on main proces `filter.$regex.constructor` does return `[Function: RegExp]`.

The problem is that third party library([NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb)) checks if the variable a real RegExp is using:

```
exports.isRegExp = function(obj){return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object RegExp]'};
```

which returns false. Besides that the Regex doesn't work at all without wrapping it in `new RegExp()`.

Comment: `new RegExp(/.../)` looks wrong. `/.../` is already a `RegExp` object.

Comment: `/inventaris/i` and `new RegExp('inventaris', 'i')` give exactly the same result

Comment: I think you will have to use `eval(filter.$regex)`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally anything that gets sent via Electron IPC first gets serialized to JSON, if you call `JSON.stringify(/inventaris/i)` you'll get `{}` which is what will probably be sent across. Since the default serialization doesn't work in this case you need to convert the Regexp into something that will be serialized into a form that you can convert back into a Regexp after deserialization on the other end. For example:

```
const originalRegex = /inventaris/i
// this is what should be sent via IPC
const payload = { source: regex.source, flags: regex.flags }
// convert the payload back to a Regexp on the other end
const reconstructedRegex = new Regexp(payload.source, payload.flags)
```